# Jquery bind scroll listener dynamiclly

Tags: jquery, dynamic, scroll, listener

I know how to bind a dynamic click listener,just

```
$("#static").on("click","#dynamic",function{.....});
```

But it wont work with

```
$("#static").on("scroll","#dynamic",function{.....});
```

The parent element can't scroll,so the parent element can't propagation the scroll event to its child.
How can I bind the scroll event to a dynamic element?

Comment: You can use `$(document).on("scroll","#dynamic",function(){.....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll events don't bubble so you can't bind a scroll event to a dynamically added element

> In all browsers, the `load`, `scroll`, and `error` events (e.g., on an `<img>`
>   element) do not bubble.

[jquery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: But it seems I can use the deprecated function live() to make it work.Am I right?

Comment: if the event doesn't bubble do you think live will work?